# Windows console command to open multiple pages in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line, windows-xp, batch-file

How do I open multiple pages in Internet Explorer 7 with a single DOS command? Is a batch file the only way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: not DOS. Windows command-line environment. CMD.EXE is a console-mode Win32 executable and does not use DOS interfaces. Many new commands and features added to Windows NT CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A batch file will work as a quick and dirty solution.

```
@echo off
@setlocal

:openurl
set url=%~1

if "%url:~0,4%" == "http" (
   start "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "%url%"
)
if NOT "%url:~0,4%" == "http" (
   start "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://%url%"
)

shift
if "%~1" == "" goto :end
goto :openurl

:end
```

Edit: added support for domain names without http handler prefix.

Comment: This works well. Full URLs must be specified parameters: stackoverflow.com doesn't work while http://stackoverflow.com works.

Comment: See the answer (currently) [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118748/#118763) for a solution that doesn't require a `cmd.exe` window appearing.

Answer (score 4):

1. open a txt file with .txt extension
2. Add the below lines

   - start www.google.com
   - start www.yahoo.com
   - start www.microsoft.com
3. save the file, select rename on the file and change the extension from .txt to .cmd
4. double click the .cmd file to execute

Comment: Since you've just provided a batch file, this response doesn't answer the question of whether a batch file is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to include multiple URLs as command-line parameters.  Here is a a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tonyschr/archive/2007/01/19/ie-automation-amp-tabs.aspx) which details another (fairly convoluted) way to do it via Javascript.

Comment: +1 for a alternative to the longer batch file [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118748/#118796). Also for a solution that doesn't require a `cmd.exe` window showing

Answer (score 1):

I’ve downloaded the software that does exactly this. From a command line open several websites without having to copy, paste VB scripts or batch files, etc… It’s available at http://www.multiwebpageopener.com.