# batch file to open multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I want to multiple URLs in internet explorer in the same window, but new tabs.

I have a list of about 6 URLs that I use daily, and I want to create a single batch file to open them all.

Also, if there is a way to do this using JS that would be great.

Comment: So what have you written so far? What is the problem with your code? Can you post use the batch file you have written, that does not work, so we can see what the problem is and help you correct it?

Comment: I've seen (and answered) this exact question before, I think.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Windows console command to open multiple pages in Internet Explorer 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/118748/113116), [How to launch multiple Internet Explorer windows/tabs from batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/188850/113116), [Script to automate URL opening in multiple tabs in Firefox or Opera from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3752133/113116).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
start "" "http://bing.com"
start "" "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535049/batch-file-to-open-multiple-urls"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and came up with the following code.  I wanted to obtain basic movie information for use in creating a DVD case outer jacket.  I wanted to review rottentomatoes and imdb ratings as well as google movie images.  That would be 3 urls using tabs in explorer launched from the win7 command line.  The batch file would be run using, for example

showmovieinfo The Hunger Games

```
@ECHO OFF
REM BRING UP REFERENCE MATERIAL FOR THE SUPPLIED MOVIE TITLE
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Done
SET showmovieinfo=%1
:Test
SHIFT
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Done
SET showmovieinfo=%showmovieinfo%+
FOR %%F IN (%1) DO SET showmovieinfo=%showmovieinfo%%%F
GOTO Test
:Done
SET E1=start /d explorer.exe http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=%showmovieinfo%
SET E2=start /d explorer.exe http://www.imdb.com/find?q=%showmovieinfo%
SET E3=start /d explorer.exe http://www.google.com/search?num=10"&"hl=en"&"q=FILM+%showmovieinfo%"&"um=1"&"ie=UTF-8"&"tbm=isch
%E1%
%E2%
%E3%
```